# Comparison of two files with awk command

Tags: unix, awk

I have got two files, say `file1` and `file2`, to be compared and put it in `file3`.

`file1`:

```
red
green
blue
red
yellow
pink
orange
```

`file2`:

```
domain1,red,-
domain2,-,green
domain3,blue,-
domain4,yellow,pink
domain5,grey,orange
```

Now I need output as follows in `file3`:

```
domain1,red
domain2,green
domain3,blue
domain1,red
domain4,yellow
domain4,pink
domain5,orange
```

For each record in `file1`, if matched, it needs to produce `$1` as mandatory and the matching value either `$2` or `$3` from `file2`, if both($2,$3) are matched, then it should be in two records (single record also would do) as "domain5,pink,orange".

I'm newbie to awk command. Please help me achieve this with `awk`!

I have this simple command which is not sufficing my condition

```
awk 'NR==FNR{x[$1];next}($2,$3) in x' FS=',' file1 file2 >file3
```

Comment: pls explain why there are two `domain1,red` in output? typo?

Comment: as i have red twice in file1, the search pattern on red is happening twice.

Comment: uh.. I see it now.. my answer removes duplicates implicitly, not correct... removing..

Comment: Hi Kent, ur answer wud suffice my requirement , as infact i need duplication removal.but had a small query, what if i need to implement the same with case insensitive!!will the same command suffice ? Regards

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=","} 
         NF>1 {s[$2]=s[$3]=$1;} 
         NF==1 {print s[$1],$1}' input2 input1
```

**Output**

```
domain1,red
domain2,green
domain3,blue
domain1,red
domain4,yellow
domain4,pink
domain5,orange
```

Comment: Hi,the above awk command is giving only the second column in the above mentioned OP which is required.

Comment: Nice solution @perreal … If you don't mind can you please explain this syntax - `s[$2]=s[$3]=$1;`?

Comment: Thanks for ur response Perreal,Im getting OP as this ,red ,green ,blue ,red ,yellow ,pink ,orange ...... all in different rows. it is excluding $1 values in file2 (domain1 ......)

Comment: @user2407164, the first argument should be the second file, not the first file.

Comment: @Jaypal, thanks, it sets `s[$2]` and `s[$3]` to `$1` at the same time. For example, `s['yellow']=s['pink']='domain4'`.